# How to join many to many in createQuery()

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine, many-to-many, createquery

I'm working on my portfolio, and I got a page where I show my project. I created 2 cayegorie for now: Programmation and artistic. Each of my project can be a programming project, an artistique project or both. There for, I made a table project and a table categorie and they are join with a many to many relationship. So far, no probleme.

I started to create my query in the repository file of my project entitie. The problem is when I try to join my project entitie and my categorie entitie, it doesn't look like it works, because I specefy that I want just the project that have at least programmation for categorie at least. But it still returns me ALL the project when it should only give me 2 of them.

Did I made my JOIN right?

Here are the entities (watch out for the french!):
Project:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Projet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pt_projet");
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetDepot")
 */
class Projet
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    //ID du projet
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_tag", type="string",length=255, unique=true)
     */
    //Tag du projet
    protected $tag;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjetInt", mappedBy="projetId", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $descriptions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_img", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    //Nom du fichier de l'image du projet
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_technologie_utilisee", type="text", length=200)
     */
    //Text qui liste tout les technologies utilisées pour le projet
    protected $technologie;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_annee", type="integer", length=4)
     */
    //Année de réalisation du projet
    protected $annee;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="projets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pro_type", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    //Clef étrangère du type de projet
    //Le type de projet ne correspond pas à la catégore. Il peu être Unity, flash, image, vidéo, etc. Il permet de savoir quelle page charger pour pouvoir intégrer le projet dans le portfolio.
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_fichier", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    //Nom du fichier du projet
    private $fichier;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categorie", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    //La ou les catégories du projet
    private $categories;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->descriptions=new ArrayCollection();
        $this->categories=new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set technologie
     *
     * @param string $technologie
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setTechnologie($technologie)
    {
        $this->technologie = $technologie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get technologie
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTechnologie()
    {
        return $this->technologie;
    }

    /**
     * Set annee
     *
     * @param integer $annee
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setAnnee($annee)
    {
        $this->annee = $annee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get annee
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAnnee()
    {
        return $this->annee;
    }

    /**
     * Set fichier
     *
     * @param string $fichier
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setFichier($fichier)
    {
        $this->fichier = $fichier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fichier
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFichier()
    {
        return $this->fichier;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param Type $type
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setType(Type $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return Type 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Add categories
     *
     * @param Categorie $categories
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function addCategory(Categorie $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove categories
     *
     * @param Categorie $categories
     */
    public function removeCategory(Categorie $categories)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }


    /**
     * Add description
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $description
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function addDescription(\PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $description)
    {
        $this->description[] = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove description
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $description
     */
    public function removeDescription(\PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $description)
    {
        $this->description->removeElement($description);
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

Category:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Catégorie
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pt_categorie");
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PublicBundle\Entity\CategorieDepot")
 */
class Categorie
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    //ID de la catégorie
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="cat_tag", type="string",length=255, unique=true)
     */
    //Tag de la catégorie
    protected $tag;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set tag
     *
     * @param string $tag
     * @return Categorie
     */
    public function setTag($tag)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tag
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTag()
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }
}
```

And the reposetory:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * ProjetDepot
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ProjetDepot extends EntityRepository
{

    public function rechercherProjets($lang, $cat)
    {

        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT p.tag,
                    p.image,
                    pi.nom,
                    pi.descriptionCours,
                    pi.descriptionComplete,
                    pi.roles,
                    p.technologie,
                    pi.aptitudesDeveloppees,
                    p.annee
            FROM PublicBundle:Projet p
            JOIN PublicBundle:ProjetInt pi
            WITH p.id=pi.projetId
            JOIN PublicBundle:Categorie c
            WHERE pi.langue=:lang
            AND c.tag=:cat'
        )->setParameters(array('lang'=>$lang,'cat'=>$cat))->getResult();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public function rechercherProjets($lang, $cat) { 
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
         ->innerJoin ('p.description', 'pi') 
         ->innerJoin('p.categories', 'pc')
         ->andWhere('pc.tag = :cat')
         ->andWhere('pi.langue = :lang')
         ->setParameters(array('lang'=>$lang,'cat'=>$cat));

     return $qb->getQuery()->getResult() 
}
```

Comment: It seem to works, but I have a few questions. First, is there a way to do the same request but  with createQuery insted of createQueryBuilder? Second, when I tri to access the tag of my project, it doesn't want to let me to (projet["tag"]) I used a foreach in my twig ({% for projet in projets %}) . The only way I found to make it work is to wright->select('
      p.tag AS tag')

Comment: ^Forget about the question about tag, I find out my mistake, but I got a new one, how do I access "nom" that is in my porjetint entitie? For exemple, I use {{ projet.tag  }} to get the tag, but how do I get "nom"?

Comment: Hello.  i think using QueryBuilder is better way... and yes..  you can do the same request...  for example you can print SQL query $qb->getQuery()->getSql();

Comment: what you mean "nom"? I don't understand

Comment: "nom" is just the name of a field in my projetint entitie. I was just wondering how I access it since I can't do {{ projet.nom }}

Comment: for access to fields in twig like {{ entity.field}} you must first describe getter for this field.